# XSLT: How to preserve whitespace between elements?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a new requirement to make transformed XML a bit more readable, ie preserving the cr, tabs and other white space between elements.

I can't seem to figure out how to preserve the whitespace.

Can someone please help ?

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

**XSL File:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/m:Wix">
    <xsl:message>Matched Wix</xsl:message>
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Insert the new include processing instruction -->
      <xsl:processing-instruction name="include">
        <xsl:text>$(sys.CURRENTDIR)src/includes/globals.wxi </xsl:text>
      </xsl:processing-instruction>
      <!-- place the existing children into the output -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/> 
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"><?include $(sys.CURRENTDIR)src/includes\globals.wxi ?><Fragment>
    </Fragment></Wix>
```

**Desired Output**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <?include $(sys.CURRENTDIR)src/includes\globals.wxi ?>
    <Fragment>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: What does "xlst" mean?  Good question !! It means I'm tried of retyping autocorrect on the mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three whitespace text nodes in your input: the two that are siblings of the Fragment element, and the one that is a child of the Fragment element.

The first two are not copied to your output because your template for the m:Wix element ignores them: it does `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/>` which only selects element children, not text node children.

The whitespace text content of Fragment is processed, and is retained in your output.

Now: you say two things in your question: (a) you want to make the output readable, and (b) you want to preserve the whitespace present in the input. I would suggest that (b) is not the best way of achieving (a). The best way of achieving (a) is to ignore the whitespace present in the input, and use `xsl:output indent="yes"` to add new whitespace in the output.

However, if you do want to copy the whitespace from the input to the output, you need to use `select="node()"` rather than `select="*"` when processing the children of an element.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the line break, `&#xa;` and tab entity, `&#9;` by adding following text before and after process instruction. And be sure to add the indent output header towards the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/m:Wix">
    <xsl:message>Matched Wix</xsl:message>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:text>&#xa; &#9;</xsl:text>      
      <!-- Insert the new include processing instruction -->
      <xsl:processing-instruction name="include">
        <xsl:text>$(sys.CURRENTDIR)src/includes/globals.wxi </xsl:text>
      </xsl:processing-instruction>
      <xsl:text>&#xa; &#9;</xsl:text>      
      <!-- place the existing children into the output -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/>        
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, use multiple non-break space entities `&#160;` in place of tab for more precise alignment:

```
<xsl:text>&#xa;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</xsl:text>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <?include $(sys.CURRENTDIR)src/includes/globals.wxi?>
    <Fragment>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The formats are not consistent, different files from different sources.  Hard coding the format is not a viable solution, but may need it as a fall back position.

Answer (score 0):

My tool of choice for pretty printing is xmlint.

```
xmllint --format old.xml > new.xml
```

But I do see you're adding a processing instruction. So xslt is needed.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    exclude-result-prefixes="m">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="m:Wix">
        <xsl:message>Matched Wix</xsl:message>
        <Wix>

            <xsl:call-template name="CR"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="TAB"/>

            <!-- Insert the new include processing instruction -->
            <xsl:processing-instruction name="include">
                <xsl:text>$(sys.CURRENTDIR)src/includes/globals.wxi</xsl:text>
            </xsl:processing-instruction>

            <!-- place the existing children into the output -->
            <xsl:apply-templates/> 
        </Wix>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="m:Fragment">
        <Fragment>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Fragment>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="CR">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>      
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="TAB">
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If your real XML gets more complicated, you may want to xmllint first. Then do a simple xslt to add the processing instruction. Xmllint is pretty-whitespace aware, xslt you have to bake it in.